# How can I assign an item to a user id in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Am new to rails and i have an application that allows the user to sign in and create a deadline for a project, my question is am using devise and I want to set it so when a new deadline is created i assign it to the users id. I tried the following in my new and create methods:

```
class DeadlinesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @deadline = current_user.deadlines.new
end

def create
    @deadline = current_user.deadlines.new(params[:deadline].permit(:title, :date, :description))
    if @deadline.save
        redirect_to @deadline
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @deadline = Deadline.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @deadline = Deadline.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @deadlines = Deadline.all
    @deadlines = Deadline.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
end

def update
    @deadline = Deadline.find(params[:id])

    if @deadline.update(params[:deadline].permit(:title, :date, :description))
        redirect_to @deadline
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @deadline = Deadline.find(params[:id])
    @deadline.destroy

    redirect_to deadlines_path

end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:deadline).permit(:title, :date, :description)
end

 end
```

When I try `@deadline = current_user.deadlines.new` I get in error as `undefined method deadlines' for #<User:0x007fa37b6127d8>`?

Comment: Can we see your `User` model? Because I would guess that you're lacking this in your model: `has_many :deadlines`.

Comment: Am getting unknown attribute user_id, does that mean i need to add a user_id column to my deadlines table if so how would i go about doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add `user_id` column to deadlines table.

In the terminal, navigate to your Rails app and type:

`rails generate migration add_user_id_to_deadlines user_id:integer`

This will create a migration automatically that has the `user_id` column in the deadlines table. You can then migrate the database again to add the latest changes:

`rake db:migrate`

Also modify your deadline.rb to include `belongs_to :user` and user.rb to include `has_many :deadlines`